# Building 32-bit mysql c++ connector from source on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c++, mysql, linker, mysql-connector

I want to build a Win32 version of mysqlcppconn.dll from source so I can use it in my Win32 applications. I am running on 64bit Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012. I used CMake to create the solution files to build with MSVC2012. The x64 builds fine and I am able to link with my program compiled in x64 mode.

However, there is no Win32 configuration available when trying to compile the source. I tried creating a new one, with the copy settings from x64. When I try to compile, it gives me this error:

Debug\mysql_art_resultset.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Does anyone know why this happens? Where should I look for the solution? In the CMake settings? Or the property manager in MSVC2012?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Target Machine` to X86 in `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced`